# In Kotlin, how to delegate to an interface and provide only a no-arg public constructor?

Tags: guava, kotlin

The problem arises from the fact that Kotlin [class delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#class-delegation) allows to delegate only to constructor parameters, thus seemingly forcing you to provide constructor with an argument.

Below is my original question pertaining to a concrete use case of this problem.

---

I want to do the following:

```
val myTable1: MyTable = MyTable()
```

where

- `MyTable` inherits from [ImmutableTable](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) ([src](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html#line.45)) or at least [Table](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table)
- and I do not have to manually delegate all the `Table` methods to some base implementation.

I also want to avoid the following:

```
val myTable2: MyTable = MyTable.build()
```

i.e. I do not want to be forced to use companion objects / static factory methods.

I tried to extend `ImmutableTable`, but I am getting `This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here`.

I tried to extend `Table` interface and delegate to it (to avoid reimplementing methods) but then I am forced to provide an instance of `Table` as constructor parameter. I cannot just initialize it in `init {}` block.

Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/konrad-jamrozik/3bdf9a306fea6a2e25f42ee8b4bc5aa8) for my exact attempts.

Kotlin version used: `1.0.2`

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve? I guess it is by design that deriving from `ImmutableTable` is not easy but I suspect that's not your end goal.

Comment: My end goal is to be able to call a no-arg constructor of a class that inherits from (extends/implements) Table interface. At the same time, I do not want to be forced to reimplement all the Table methods. I hoped I can inherit from ImmutableTable as it implements many methods of Table, but probably you are right that ImmutableTable cannot be inherited by design (my mistake then). In such case I have to work with Table directly. But then if I want to delegate to Table, to avoid reimplementing methods, I am forced to use a constructor that takes Table as arg.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but: Does [`ForwardingTable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingTable.html) help here? It, unlike `ImmutableTable`, is extensible. You could make it forward to an `ImmutableTable` delegate.

Comment: Yes, thanks! `ForwardingTable` provides `delegate` method which I can use instead of Kotlin's [class delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#class-delegation). The `delegate` method allows me to delegate to a field instantiated in class constructor. Kotlin's class delegation forbids this: the delegation can happen only to a constructor parameter, not a field initialized in constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, Guava has `ForwardingTable` that can accomplish this. But here's another option that should work even for interfaces where there isn't a "forwarding" version defined.

```
class MyTable private constructor(table: Table<Int, Int, Int>) : Table<Int, Int, Int> by table {

    constructor() : this(TreeBasedTable.create()) // or a different type of table if desired

}
```

Comment: Why a private primary constructor plus a public secondary constructor instead of a single public primary constructor with default arguments? i.e. Why not simply `class MyTable(table: Table<Int, Int, Int> = TreeBasedTable.create()) : Table<Int, Int, Int> by table`?

Comment: That should work fine as well. I was going under the assumption that it was not desirable for calling code to be able to supply a `Table` implementation at all.